# Google.maps.ImageMapType getTileUrl maximum length

Tags: geoserver, wms, google-maps, sld, http

I am using `google.maps.ImageMapType` to render a GeoServer WMS to Google Map. When a request is made, it uses GET.

I am concern the WMS getMap length might exceed 4k in length due to a requirement to embed very long sld_body in the GetMap request. Is there anyway to change this to a POST instead of a GET?

Due to network restriction, I can't use the `SLD&` parameter and provide a URL instead. It has to be `sld_body&` which can potentially be long.

Comment: If you do a GetCapabilities request on your GeoServer WMS, does it list POST as an option?